# Tracking multipel opject using Optical Flow PyrLK from haar detection result

Tags: c++, linux, opticalflow

I am trying to track multiple object (cars) in videos using Optical Flow PyrLK from haar detection result but the problem is some time the haar detection (object) does not appear in the frames !
How can I track an object that the haar detection (object) does not appear in few frames ?? how can I approximate it is place automatically ,,,

I am trying to find the object using Optical flow PyrLK ... but this technique lost when the haar detection (object) does not appear

Any suggestion ideas ??? please.....

Green Rect = Haar Detection result, Red Point = Corners from GoodFeaturestoTrack

[image: Image frame 1 : There is Haar detection result]

[image: Image frame 2 : Haar detection (object) does not appear]

this is my code : 
can you give me solution ??

```
video >> prev_frame;
Rect roi = Rect(50, 180, 540, 240);
prevROI=prev_frame(roi);
cvtColor(prevROI, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
gray.convertTo(prev_img, CV_8UC1);

while(true)
{
    video >> frameROI;
    Rect roi = Rect(50, 180, 540, 240);
    Mat ROI=frameROI(roi);
    cvtColor(ROI, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); //=====> RGB to Grayscale
    gray.convertTo(imgROI, CV_8UC1);

    vector<Rect> cars;
    Casmobil.detectMultiScale(gray, cars, 1.1, 3,
                              CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,
                              Size(0,0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect square = cars[i];
        areax = (cars[i].x + cars[i].width*0.5);
        areay = (cars[i].y + cars[i].height*0.5);

        Point cen_point = Point(areax ,areay);

        rectangle(ROI, square,CV_RGB(0,255,0),2,8,0);
        circle(ROI, cen_point, 3,CV_RGB(255, 0, 0),-2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect square2 = cars[i];
        cropcars = imgROI(square2);
        ROIOF = ROI(square);

        //prev_frame
        goodFeaturesToTrack(cropmobil, prevframe_corners,maxCorners,
                            qualityLevel,minDistance,Mat(),
                            blockSize,useHarrisDetector,k);
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_img, imgROI, prevframe_corners,
                             frame_corners, found, error,
                             Size(win_size, win_size), maxlevel,termcrit);

        Rect box = boundingRect(frame_corners);
        rectangle(ROIOF, box, CV_RGB(0,255,255),2,8,0);
        Boxx = (box.x + box.width*0.5);
        boxy = (box.y + box.height*0.5);
        cen = Point(boxx, boxy);
        circle(ROIF, cen, 3, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), -1);

        for( int j = 0; j < frame_corners.size(); j++ )
        {
            circle(ROIOF, frame_corners[j], 2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), -1);
            circle(ROIOF, prevframe_corners[j], 2, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), -1);
            line(ROIOF,frame_corners[j], cen, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0),2, 8, 0);
        }

        prev_img = imgROI.clone();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Haar detection for *every* frames, so why are you using LK tracking?

In object tracking, since Haar detection is very heavy weight and slow, people usually apply Haar detection in first frame and *track* the object using other methods.

In your case, using [CamShift](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/df8/tutorial_py_meanshift.html) seems to do the job. So, you do a Haar detection in first frame and let CamShift track the cars.

Note that CamShift algorithm is completely based on image histogram, so in cases where color of object is considerably different from its background, it works well.

Comment: in this case, if i'm still using Optical Flow LK to track. i must apply Haar detection in first frame and track the object using Optical Flow ??/

Comment: @Cong_Cong Yes. So, you first do Haar detection to find where your object is, then find its good features (`goodFeaturesToTrack`) and finally let LKT to track the feature points. Also for better accuracy you can do Haar detection once every a few frames.

Comment: in the code that I made above, I implement the Optical Flow PyrLK on each haar on every frame, but the problem is when on the frame is not detected the existence of haar, then the optical flow is also not there.
There is a solution to this problem may be?

Comment: @Cong_Cong If your intention is to _track_ the cars, so why do you _detect_ them (using Haar classification)? As far as I know, people first _detect_ an object and then _track_ it. Haar is for _detection_ and KLT for _tracking_. As you know KLT takes two list of points, one for current frame and other for previous frame. So you should _detect_ first and then find its good features and feed them to KLT to _track_ those features. Also it's worth mentioning that during KLT some of points may be lost. In this case, you should _re-detect_ and _re-find_ good features and do KLT again. Sounds clear?

Comment: @Cong_Cong However in my opinion, in this case it may be worth taking a look at CamShift. OpenCV has an example exactly same as yours, tracking cars.